# Is the gerund being used in a proper way: "His job is driving a cab."

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund

I am not sure if the following sentence is grammatically correct.

> His job is **driving** a cab.

I believe the gerund cannot be used in this way.  Am I right?

Would it mean the same to say? His job is to drive a cab

What are the differences between these two statements? Are they both possible?

Comment: Welcome fer - Why do you think a gerund can't be used that way?

Comment: Would it mean the same to say?  His job is to drive a cab

Comment: What are the differences between these two statements? Are they both possible?

Comment: @fer Please feel free to [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/178389/edit) in any additional details or thoughts about this. Don't use comments for that.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that *Playing football is Gareth Bale's job* and *Gareth Bale's job is playing football* are both perfectly valid and usually mean exactly the same thing. As does *Gareth Bale's job is to play football*, but *To play football is Gareth Bale's job* doesn't sound at all idiomatic to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah but "To play football is Gareth Bale's destiny" might be proclaimed by a speaker.....:)

Answer (score 1):

> **Driving a cab** is his job.
>   **Playing tennis** is their favorite sport.

**Gerund phrases can be used as subjects in sentences with be** and **a predicate nominative.** So, you can invert those sentences to:

His job **is driving a cab**.

Their favorite sport **is playing tennis**.

**His job is to drive a cab, and not to sit around playing cards.**

The emphasis is different. The meaning is basically the same but,  let's say for simplicity's sake, the use of **drive a cab after to** is more objective oriented and is a predicate but not a  predicate nominative. It makes a statement about his job. As opposed to just being informative.